# How to create a parameterized materialized view in kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is it possible to pass parameters to materialize views?
if not is there a workaround to achieve same result.

Problem:
The function depending upon the parameter uses different column values to calculate the desired results.

eg: For param1 the function uses col1 and col2 values,
For param2 the function uses col3 and col4 values and so on.

The only solution I have right now is to create different materialize views for each distinct parameter value that is possible, is there a better way than this?

Need to find a way to pass param value to the below mentioned code after creation of materialized view.

```
    TableName
    | project channel, processName, product,
        TAT = case(param == 'api1', tat1,
                param == 'api2', tat2,
                param == 'api3', tat3,
                param == 'api4', tat4,
                param == 'api5', tat5,tat6),
        Status = case(param == 'api1', status1,
                param == 'api2', status2,
                param == 'api3', status3,
                param == 'api4', status4,
                param == 'api5', status5,status6),
        ingestion_time = asyncEndTime
       | summarize 
       Tot_Cases_withNull = count(),//countif(isnotempty(Status))),
       Success = countif(Status == 'S'),
       Failures = countif(Status == 'F'),
       avg_TAT = toreal(avgif(TAT,isnotempty(Status))),
       bucket1 = (countif(TAT <= b1 )),
       bucket2 = (countif(TAT >  b1 and TAT <= b2)),
       bucket3 = (countif(TAT >  b2 and TAT <= b3)),
       bucket4 = (countif(TAT >  b3 and TAT <= b4)),
       bucket5 = (countif(TAT >  b4 and TAT <= b5)),
       bucket6 = (countif(TAT >  b5 ))
       by bin(ingestion_time,15m),product
```

Comment: Are `col1`, `col2` in your example the group by keys of the materialized view? If so, there's no way to make these dynamic. You need to create a separate materialized view for each group by keys combination.

Comment: yes, I was hoping for another workaround than that if possible, but it does not seem possible